# How to parse xml to tree using SWT or Jface? And How to synchronize the tree and the xml?

Tags: java, tree, swt, jface

I'd like to build a tree like following using SWT or JFace:
http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/adiehelp/v5r1m1/topic/com.ibm.etools.xsdeditor.doc/images/ncalxml.gif

How to build the tree base on an XML? and how to synchronize the tree and the xml(When I update the tree node(or xml), the xml(or tree) should be updated at the same time).

Could anyone give me a tutorial?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at Structured Source Editors framework from WebTools project - http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/wst/components/sse/overview.html

Note it is pretty standalone, so you won't have to add whole WTP to your project.

It provides you a base class for editors with source/grid/design tabs, XML parser that properly handles broken code (XML is invalid when the user is typing so most parsers fail) and a DOM where you can listen for events.

Comment: Thanks, but the URL above is only an overview. Is there any tutorial?

Comment: I don't know... I learned how to use it by looking at the source code. It is pretty approachable. Note that their XML editor provides ready to use hooks for adding your own tab - you may try looking at different Webtools editors (e.g. JSP page editor) to see how they work with DOM. Note that there is little difference whether editor works with JSP, HTML or XML - the interfaces are same so you can use any editor as a reference.